# Python Subclass Tracking - Metaclasses vs Builtin

Tags: python, django, metaclass, subclass

For a Django tab library, I created an architecture that uses tracking of marked subclasses.

To do this, I created a base class and then derive all tab classes from it. I track the descendant classes using a function that recursively uses the `cls.__subclasses__()` method.

In order to know which subclasses are leaf classes / real tabs, I chose to do this the manual way by adding `__tab__ = True` to any class I want to show up as a tab. The reason for this is that I'm creating other abstraction classes below `TabView` that shouldn't show up as tabs. Maybe this could be re-written as a decorator.

Example:

```
def get_descendants(cls):
    """Returns all subclasses for cls, and their sublasses, and so on..."""
    descendants = []
    subclasses = cls.__subclasses__()
    for subclass in subclasses:
        descendants.append(subclass)
        descendants += get_descendants(subclass)
    return descendants

def TabView(object):
    def _tab_group_members(self):
        descendants = get_descendants(TabView)
        return [d for d in descendants if '__tab__' in d.__dict__]
    (...)

def ConcreteTab(TabView):
    __tab__ = True
```

Now I started reading Marty Alchin's "Pro Django" book. In there, he proposes the usage of metaclasses to track subclasses:

```
class SubclassTracker(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        try:
            if TrackedClass not in bases:
                return
        except NameError:
            return
        TrackedClass._registry.append(cls)

class TrackedClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = SubclassTracker
    _registry = []
```

What are the advantages of the metaclass approach? Is it better than using `__subclasses__()`?

Comment: Never invent `__foo__` names.

Comment: @yak thanks for the comment. so `_tab` would be better? or `_tab_`? (i'll probably replace it with a decorator anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using metaclasses means that all the information you stored inside the class itself.  It also means the info is stored as the classes are created, rather than scanning all of them afterwards.  This means that all you need to worry about is creating classes - they are tracked automatically.